# Clarification on the gamblers fallacy

Tags: bias, fallacy

I recently learned about the gamblers fallacy and I understand the idea that past independent events have no bearing on the odds of the next coin flip. Specifically what cleared this up for me is that
The probability of 20 heads, then 1 tail is $0.5^{20} \times 0.5 = 0.5^{21}$
The probability of 20 heads, then 1 head is $0.5^{20} \times 0.5 = 0.5^{21}$.
The above example was helpful to make it more intuitive why this is a fallacy but this raised a new question for me. Often, if people are too lucky, professionals use those numbers from above to "prove" that the person was cheating or that the game was rigged. How can professionals use these numbers to make such claims when there was simply a 50% chance of the coin being flipped in that order every time? Are they not falling victim to the gamblers fallacy when they do this? Could someone clarify this for me or help explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a 'professional' doing something like this?

Comment: @mkt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ko3TdPy0TU this link shows a math YouTube channel doing something to this fashion

Comment: When I have time I will post an answer from the Bayesian point of view. In short: if you observe an event that sounds unlikely, such as "several heads in a row", then there are two possible explanations: (1) I was just lucky. (2) The coin is loaded. Use Bayes' theorem to calculate the probability of each of these two explanations conditional to the observed event. Loaded coins are extremely rare, so if the event is not too unlikely, high conditional probability that I was just lucky. But if the event is extremely unlikely, then conditional probability that coin was loaded goes up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to encourage intuition about 'too lucky': If a person flips a 'fair' coin 20 times, and it comes up heads each time, a statistician might say something like "A 'fair coin' my foot!". Why so? Because we have a model of **collections of fair coin flips**—and generally, collections of probabilities of independent events with known individual probability—in the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). If we know the size of the collection (i..e number of coin flips), and the probability of a single independent event (0.5 for a fair coin), then we can use the binomial distribution to answer questions like "What is the probability of observing $x=20$ 'successes' (i.e. 'heads') out of $n=20$ coin flips, on a fair coin where the probability of heads = $0.5$?"

It turns out the answer to that specific question is, in the immortal words of Oliver Wendel Jones, "Diddly $\div$ squat" (more precisely, this specific probability is $Pr(X=20|n=20,p=0.5)=0.5^{20} = 0.000000953674$, or less than 1 in a million). The expected value of observed heads out of 20 flips is 10 (probability 0.176), and the probability of observing a number of heads in the range 7–13 is >0.95… 20 heads is just too unlikely.

So the 'too lucky' is not in the 21st head: it's in a string of wins that gets too improbable. Of course the actual calculations performed by a gambling house will also take into account the number of gamblers one observes playing a game, a history of play on previous occasions, etc.

Comment: So when looking at the link to binomial distribution I tried to read it but it seems beyond my current grasp of this subject and mathematics. From your answer and my limited understanding though, it seems that the fact remains that the odds of someone flipping x (x being some arbitrary large number) heads in a row quickly become close to zero. This leads me to believe that at the yth (y being some number less than x in which the binomial theorem says the odds of another consecutive win is very unlikely) I should guess tails. This seems to be the gamblers fallacy though.

Comment: Is it just required for me to understand the binomial theorem further before I can grasp this?

Comment: @TristanBrown If the binomial distribution is too complicated, perhaps look at the [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) instead. It is related but corresponds to the simplified experiment "flip coins repeatedly but stop when you get a tails", rather than "flip coins repeatedly and count all heads and tails".

Comment: Tristan Brown: Notice that there are two different questions: (i) what is the probability of a single coin flip coming up heads **given that i have just flipped 19 heads in a row already** – 0.5, and (ii) what is the probability of a series of 20 coin flips in a row coming up heads – less than 1 in a million. Notice that these two questions have sharply different answers. The Gamblers Fallacy is, in a sense, falsely assuming that the answer to the second question (profoundly improbable) somehow describes the answer to the first question (a 50/50 chance).

Comment: @Alexis So I looked into the Geometric distribution as recommended and this gave a better understanding of how we calculate these numbers and even helped me understand the binomial distribution. I think your second comment is where my confusion lies. I don't see why we say you should only look at the first question while gambling, rather than the second question which leads us to our Gamblers fallacy. I don't mean to beat a dead horse here but I would really like to intuitively understand this fallacy and at the moment it's still not really clear. How do we decide which question to ask?

Comment: No one is saying we should only pose or answer a single question. As I said in my second comment, the Gambler's Fallacy results from something like an assumption that the probability of a **sequence of wins** in independent flips (or whatever event is important to the game) should be interpreted as changing the probability of the next independent flip. Two different probabilities, and the fallacy is conflating them.